# checking an array for allowed characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-matching

I dont understand why this code is still returning false even if I type abcdef into the prompt when it appears as it should return true.

```
var userinput = prompt('Input characters:');

var lowercase = userinput.toLowerCase();

var allowedcharacters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

function match(input, statement) {
    for (var i = 0; i < statement.length; i++) {
        if (input.indexOf(statement[i]) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if (lowercase == allowedcharacters){
  alert(true);
}
else{
  alert(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't calling your `match` function. You probably want:

```
if (match(lowercase, allowedcharacters)){
  alert(true);
}
else{
  alert(false);
}
```

**EDIT** Per request, here's a variant of `match` that returns `true` if no character matches a disallowed character:

```
function noneMatch(input, disallowed) {
    for (var i = 0; i < disallowed.length; i++) {
        if (input.indexOf(statement[i]) >= 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: how would I call the function then? sorry Im pretty new to javascript im just learning.

Comment: @TedHopp thanks. Is it possible to add another array with disallowed characters?

Comment: @ElliottDavidson - Sure. You just need to reverse the logic that you have in `match`. Instead of returning `false` whenever a character is not found, return `false` whenever a character _is_ found. However, I don't think it makes much sense to have both a list of required characters and a list of disallowed characters passed to the same function. (Presumably if it is in the disallowed list it isn't in the required list, so it would be rejected anyway.)

Comment: @TedHopp I get the idea of that but how would I do it? sorry pretty new to this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code .this one is working by looking at this try to get an idea. cheers !!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the function match you have built

Answer (score 0):

```
var userinput = prompt('Input characters:');

var lowercase = userinput.toLowerCase();

var allowedcharacters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]



if (match(lowercase,allowedcharacters)){
  alert(true);
}
else{
  alert(false);
}


//function to check
function match(input, statement) {
    for (var i = 0; i < statement.length; i++) {
        if (input.indexOf(statement[i]) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```